# Send email if URL is down for 2 times only

Tags: bash, shell

We want to check if URL is down or not. But sometimes, environment is down for maintenance for 3-4 hours and we dont want to keep sending emails during that time.

I have written a shell script for url check and running it every 30 mins using cronjob and incorporated below requirement.

The actual requirements are:

1. check if url is up.If it is down, send an email.
2. cronjob will execute the script again. If Step 1 sent an email, then send an email again asking if the environment is under maintenance?
3. cronjob will execute the script again.If it is still down,dont do anything.
4. keep checking the url, if it is responding dont do anything.But it goes down again follow step 1-3 .

The script works.

My request is, could you please review and suggest if there is nicer way to write the script since i'm learning shell script but dont know all the available options.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Checking urls from urls.txt
MAddr="jsing002@internalsvcs.pte.com"
TIME=`date +%d-%m-%Y_%H.%M.%S`
SCRIPT_LOC=/user/inf/ete4/eteabp4/eid_scripts/jsing002
for url in `awk '{print $1}' $SCRIPT_LOC/urls.txt`
do
    /usr/bin/wget -t 0 --spider --no-check-certificate $url > wget.output  2>&1
    HTTPCode=`(/usr/bin/wget -t 0 --spider --no-check-certificate $url) 2>&1 | grep HTTP| tail -1|cut -c 41-43`
        ENV=`(grep $url $SCRIPT_LOC/urls.txt | awk '{print $2}')`
        echo $HTTPCode
        E1=`/bin/grep -ise  'refused' -ise 'failed'  wget.output`
        if [ "$E1" != "" ] || [ $HTTPCode -ge 500 ]
            then
                    status="DOWN"
                    echo "Step 1"
                    echo "${ENV}""_DOWN"

                    if [ -f "${ENV}""_DOWN" ];
                        then
                            echo "step 2"
                            echo "Please check if $ENV in Maintanance window.The check for $url has failed twice.Next The next failure email will be sent if preceding test was SUCCESSFUL" | /bin/mail -s "Is $ENV in Maintanance Window ?" $MAddr
                            mv "${ENV}""_DOWN" "${ENV}""_DOWN""_2"
                            echo "Step 3"
                        elif [ -f "${ENV}""_DOWN""_2" ];
                            then
                                echo "this is elif statement"

                        else
                            echo "E1 is empty. Site is down"
                            echo "Site is down. $url is not accessible" | /bin/mail -s "$ENV is $status" $MAddr
                            touch  "${ENV}""_DOWN"
                        fi

            else    
                        if [ $HTTPCode -eq 200 ]
                            then
                                status="UP"
                                echo $status
                                rm "${ENV}""_DOWN""_2"
                        fi
        fi
done
```

Content of `urls.txt`:

```
http://mer01bmrim:30270/rim/web         E2E-RIMLITE4
http://mer01csmap:18001/console         ABP_WL-E2E1
http://mer02sitap:18051/console         ABP_WL-E2E2
http://mer03sitap:18101/console         ABP_WL_E2E3
```

Comment: Nice, but this would be more suited for Code Review.

Comment: this is first time i'm using stackoverflow.Please accept my apologies if I dont make sense.For code review,should i post this same question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it...I didn't test it so it may contain errors...

```
#!/bin/bash
#Checking urls from urls.txt

# destination address for mail
MAddr="jsing002@internalsvcs.pte.com"

# directory with the last operational stats of the sites
TMP="/tmp/site_stats" ; mkdir -p "$TMP"

#the mail that gets send the first time
Mail1() { cat<<EOF | /bin/mail -s "$ENV is Down" "$MAddr"

Site is down. $URL is not accessible

EOF
}

#the mail that gets send the second time
Mail2() { cat <<EOF | /bin/mail -s "is $1 in Maintenance Windows ?" "$MAddr"

Please check if $ENV in Maintanance window.
The check for $URL has failed twice.
The next failure email will be sent if preceding test was SUCCESSFUL

EOF
}

#the logic
while read URL ENV
do
    touch "$TMP/$ENV"
    if wget -O /dev/null "$URL" &>/dev/null
    then
        echo "up" > "$TMP/$ENV"
    else
        case $( cat "$TMP/$ENV" ) in 
        "maint." ) ;;
        "down"   ) Mail2 "$URL" "$ENV" ; echo "maint." >"$TMP/$ENV" ;;
        "up"     ) Mail1 "$URL" "$ENV" ; echo "down" >"$TMP/$ENV" ;;
        esac
    fi
done < urls.txt
```

Comment: this looks more neat. I'm trying to get this working.

Comment: If you have any questions about the code, don't hesitate to ask :-)